# Find probable primes with maximum size of n bits

Tags: c++, template

I created the following program to calculate probable primes with a maximum number of bits. It works as expected but I'm sure there must be a better way to implement `calcPrimeMaxBits`.

```cpp
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/miller_rabin.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

namespace mp = boost::multiprecision;
namespace rd = boost::random;

template<std::size_t N>
mp::cpp_int calcPrime()
{
    rd::mt11213b base_gen(clock());
    rd::independent_bits_engine<rd::mt11213b, N, mp::cpp_int> gen(base_gen);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
    {
        mp::cpp_int n = gen();
        if (miller_rabin_test(n, 25, gen))
        {
            return n;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

mp::cpp_int calcPrimeMaxBits(int maxBits)
{
    switch (maxBits)
    {
    case 100: return calcPrime<100>();
    case 101: return calcPrime<101>();
    case 102: return calcPrime<102>();
    case 103: return calcPrime<103>();
    case 104: return calcPrime<104>();
    case 105: return calcPrime<105>();
    case 106: return calcPrime<106>();
    case 107: return calcPrime<107>();
    case 108: return calcPrime<108>();
    case 109: return calcPrime<109>();
    // etc
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    for (int i = 100; i < 110; i++)
    {
        std::cout << i << ": " << calcPrimeMaxBits(i) << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed the title so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](/questions/how-to-ask), rather than how it is implemented. Please check that I haven't misrepresented your code, and correct it if I have.

Answer (score 1):

We're missing an include for `std::clock()`; in any case, I get a signed/unsigned conversion warning when using its (signed) result as input `base_gen`.  I would normally use

```
    rd::mt11213b base_gen{rd::random_device{}()};
```

As you have identified, we instantiate `calcPrime` many times, resulting in long compilation times, huge object code and poor maintainability.  What we want is a *runtime*-sized bit generator, which we can build from repeated application of a single fixed-width generator.

Rather than construct a complete generator class, I'll just create the variable-width random number in the function body.

To get a random number of length `len` bits, we can do this

```
static constexpr std::size_t limb_size = std::numeric_limits<mp::limb_type>::digits;
static rd::mt11213b base_gen{rd::random_device{}()};

rd::independent_bits_engine<rd::mt11213b, limb_size, mp::limb_type> gen{base_gen};

mp::cpp_int n = 0;
auto bits = len;
for (; bits > limb_size;  bits -= limb_size) {
    n <<= limb_size;
    n |= gen();
}
// last few leftover bits
n <<= bits;
n ^= gen();
```

Notice we use `^=` in the final invocation - it doesn't matter if we flip already-set bits, because they are still random.

We'll need to mask off excess bits if `len < limb_size`:

```
n = gen() & ((mp::limb_type{1} << len) - 1);
```

To generate numbers of *exactly* `len` bits, we could initialise `n = 1` and `bits = len - 1`.  And check that `len > 0`, of course.

---

## Modified code

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/miller_rabin.hpp>
#include <boost/random/random_device.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <random>

namespace mp = boost::multiprecision;
namespace rd = boost::random;

mp::cpp_int calcPrimeMaxBits(std::size_t len)
{
    static constexpr std::size_t limb_size = std::numeric_limits<mp::limb_type>::digits;
    static rd::mt11213b base_gen{rd::random_device{}()};

    rd::independent_bits_engine<rd::mt11213b, limb_size, mp::limb_type> gen{base_gen};

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) {
        mp::cpp_int n = 0;
        if (len < limb_size) {
            n = gen() & ((mp::limb_type{1} << len) - 1);
        } else {
            auto bits = len;
            for (; bits > limb_size;  bits -= limb_size) {
                n <<= limb_size;
                n |= gen();
            }
            n <<= bits;
            n ^= gen();
        }

        if (mp::miller_rabin_test(n, 25, gen)) {
            return n;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    for (size_t i = 100;  i < 120;  ++i) {
        std::cout << i << ": " << calcPrimeMaxBits(i) << '\n';
    }
}
```